# Failed to add replica to availability group : different sql server editions

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-group

I have 2 sql instaces with 2016 SP 2 
I verfied the version on both servers and make  sure they are identical but still cannot add replica because of this error 
[image]

the result of @@version on both servers
[image]

full error message 
[image]

Comment: Just to make sure it is the exact same version, can you please run `select @@version`on both machines and post the output?

Comment: @DanStef sure done

Comment: Is there more information in the "Full error" message? (the small symbols in the bottom left corner)

Comment: @DanStef attached .. for more info I just upgraded one node from sp1 to sp2 to solve this but it did not

Comment: Did you restart both servers?

Comment: @DanStef problem solved after removing instance and installing it again with newer SP version thanks a lot for your cooperation